# Injecting C# code inside HTML tag helpers

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core project, and in my Razor page, I have an HTML `div` element:

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" 
     style="background-color: #1ebba3; width: 25%" aria-valuenow="3" 
     aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="4">
</div>
```

I want to adjust the width of the progress-bar, and I don't want to hardcode the width (25%) into the style. I want to write the width based on a variable I have in an object in the model. How do I do this?

I can get the value from the Model like this:

```
@{ Model.Obj.Width }
```

But how can I inject it inside the HTML tag helper?

Comment: Some thing like.. `style=$"background-color: #1ebba3; width: {Model.Obj.Width}%"`

Comment: @Izzy the "$" string interpolation will not work in the html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ( ) instead of { }

```
style="background-color: #1ebba3; width: @(Model.Obj.Width)%"
```